# Failed to run Google I/O 2014 Android app

Tags: android

Google has released I/O 2014 android app, since it must be an valuable android app demo, so I decided to  [download](https://github.com/google/iosched) it  and tried to debug it. But, unfortunately, while I was trying to run it after compiling, it said "This app won't run unless you update google play services", actually the google play services on my phone(Nexus 5, Kitkat 4.4.4) is already the newest. So, in my perspective, I thought it was related to the server configurations, because the I/O app uses some google services, like google plus, google map, etc. I followed the official [instructions](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/doc/BUILDING.md), but instantly I stuck at the first step：After I renamed the package name in the manifest file(using Android Studio refactoring feature, it will change the activity names accordingly) and refactored the R class imports in the java classes(refactoring by moving the old generated R.java to the new package, it will rearrange the corresponding “.R” imports in all related classes), the app failed to run and complained as followings:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]    cmp=com.google.samples.apps.iosched/.ui.BrowseSessionsActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.google.samples.apps.iosched/com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.BrowseSessionsActivity} does  not exist.
```

My new package name is “com.enlangtech.samples.apps.iosched”. I have tried to build a trial app and I am sure now that the app package name can be different with the package that activity classes belong to. So I can’t understand where is the problem. Any one could help me? Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error after renaming/refactoring. What I did was add the `applicationId` property attribute to my build.gradle file, and set its value to the application package. 
Like this:

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "packageName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19;
    }

    buildTypes {
        release{
           runProguard true
           proguardFile file('path_to_proguard_file\\proguard-project.txt')
           proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }

        debug{
            runProguard false
        }
    }
}
```

androidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myfullpackagename"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="mypackagename">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name="package.Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="package.SettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutScreen"/>
        <service android:name="package.Service"
                 android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver android:name="package.Alarm"/>
        <receiver android:name="package.MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="package.MY_BROADCAST_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="package.MyBroadcastReceiver2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="package.MY_BROADCAST_RECEIVER_2"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It still failed. Could you please show me your build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml files? You can hide the sensitive information in them. Thank you!

Comment: @Sherlock Hi, if this answers your question could you accept it? Thank you.

Comment: ＠Blue5hift, I have accepted your answer. But can't vote up it, cause my low reputation score.